# ¿Cómo exportar a PDF con datatables.net en múltiples tablas?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo varias tablas generadas con la función de datatables.net, una en cada tab.

Y el script para poder sacar los botones de PDF, Excel... es el siguiente pero **por algún motivo no me funciona**.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable( {
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Como curiosidad, esta parte si funciona:

```
order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
```

Ataca sobre las siguientes tablas (pongo el ejemplo de una de ellas):

```
<table id="" class="table table-striped table-sm display">
            <thead class="thead">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nº factura</th> 
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Destinatario</th>
                    <th>Base Imp.</th>
                    <th>IVA</th>
                    <th>Importe IVA</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>1111</th> 
                    <th>12/03/2019</th>
                    <th>Juan</th>
                    <th>83</th>
                    <th>21</th>
                    <th>20</th>
                </tr>
                ...
           </tbody>
        </table>
```